# jQuery scrolltop firefox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

This script:

```
function onscroll(){
    document.getElementById("divs").style.top=""+$('body').scrollTop()+"px";
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hed2J/1/

Doesn't work on the latest Firefox version!

What am I doing wrong? :)
Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** *Edited with JSFiddle and full script :) as attached to an onscroll event*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have shown. Please post more of your code - the question shouldn't be dependent on external resources. Also, "doesn't work" is pretty vague

Comment: But it does "work" in other browsers/previous versions of FF?

Comment: Sorry, it works in Chrome, and here is a JSfiddle for more details :D http://jsfiddle.net/Hed2J/

Comment: Here it is attached to an onscroll event: http://jsfiddle.net/Hed2J/1/

Comment: And I haven't tested it in any previous version of FF.

Comment: please post the code _here_ (as well as in a fiddle), and clarify "doesn't work"

Comment: Done :) and @JanDvorak I decided to do that for purely testing purposes... though I could have just made any element large in size...

Comment: If you want to derive some value from a scroll position, perhaps you should react to changes in the scroll position? It's likely to be 0 on page load.

Comment: I attached it through `onscroll`, though that would suffice...

Comment: Why not use `position:fixed` to achieve that effect?

Comment: Jan, I'm using a dynamically scrolling thing. In a real life situation, it would look more like a spotify splash page... I've already finished programming it, and the div moves up (negative value multiplied) while you scroll. Nice effect to achieve, if it's cross-browser!

Comment: Just saying, animating `scrolltop` to a specific position doesn't work either in Firefox for me...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this fiddle, it is working in chrome, ie and the latest version of mozilla : http://jsfiddle.net/Hed2J/3/

I replace `$('body').scrollTop()` with `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: Woah, thanks dood. I thought I had tried it- but I guess not! Thanks a heap... Isn't it ridiculous how the easiest things turn out hardest to figure out?

Comment: For me, simply working with $(window).scrollTop() did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: This fix works for me great! And I have compared $(window) with $('body') in Chrome, they return the same value. Thanks!!

Answer (score 35):

A little off-topic, but if you want to animate using scrolltop, you must do

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

Note that we target both `html` and `body` because `html` will make scroll in Firefox works and `body` for other browsers.

Comment: `$('html,body')` selector works better than `$(window)` above since  the latter doesn't support `animate` method