# Why is scrollTop working on Chrome, but not in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to make the page smoothly scroll to the position 100px above an anchor:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
   'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-100
}, 500, 'swing', function () {
   window.location.hash = target;
   $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
});
```

This code works on Chrome, but not on Firefox and Internet Explorer. It does smoothly scroll to the right position, but not 100px above it. Can someone explain to my why this is and if there's a way to fix this?

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLddrmmq/1/.

Comment: Any errors on the Javascript console?

Comment: What is `$target`? Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Maybe a http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What does `onScroll` do?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm sorry, I should have provided a JSFiddle. There it is: https://jsfiddle.net/LLddrmmq/1/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scrolltop firefox not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776544/jquery-scrolltop-firefox-not-working)