# Using Ajax jQuery localStorage cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have done this Ajax jQuery function that saves the scroll position in a localStorage and it works fine on Chrome but it does not work on the other web browsers, what can I do to make it work on all platforms?

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AdminListUsers.aspx?column=Disabled&direc=False&a=chstat&z=+",
            success: function loadDoc() {
                $(window).unload(function () {
                    var scrollPosition = $("body").scrollTop();
                    localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", scrollPosition);
                });
                if (localStorage.scrollPosition) {
                    $("body").scrollTop(localStorage.getItem("scrollPosition"));
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

C#:

```
var toggleUrl = "AdminListUsers.aspx?column=" + (IsClicked.FirstOrDefault().Key ?? "Name") + "&direc=" + (IsClicked.FirstOrDefault().Value) + "&a=chstat&q=" + id.ToString() + "&d=" + disabled + "&z=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtSearchFor.Text);

        var hl = new HyperLink();
        hl.Text = status;
        hl.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, (disabled ? "red" : "green"));
        hl.NavigateUrl = toggleUrl;
        hl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "loadDoc();return true;");
        cell.Controls.Add(hl);
        tr.Cells.Add(cell);
```

Comment: Which browsers does it not work in? It seems fairly standard. I'm guessing IE is the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not really, it only works on Edge and Chrome. Firefox, Safari and IE is the issue.

Comment: [`scrollTop(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2) is supposed to take a `Number`, but when you get the value from `localStorage` it's a string. I'm not sure that's the problem, because `$(body).scrollTop(42)` does not work for me either in Firefox... Hmmm strange

Comment: Oh, try with `$(window).scrollTop(n)` instead of `$(body)`, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776544/jquery-scrolltop-firefox-not-working)

Comment: @qlown Good job you were correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change the `$("body").scrollTop();` to `$(window).scrollTop();`